# I am trying to solve this version of wildcard problem using typescript

Tags: typescript, string, wildcard

I am trying to solve this version of the wildcard problem using typescript. However, some of the test cases I provided are not passing.
this is the summary of how the code work.

**A balanced string is one in which every character in the string appears an equal number of times as every other character**

**For example, "ab", "aaabbb" and "ababaabb" are balanced, but "abb" and "abbaa" are not.**

```
function balanced(s: string): boolean {
  const MAX = 1000;
  let wildcards: number = 0;
  const map: { [key: string]: number } = {};
  let characterCount = 0;
  for (const char of s) {
    if (char === '*') {
      wildcards++;
    } else {
      if (!map[char]) {
        map[char] = 0;
      }
      map[char]++;
      if (map[char] > characterCount) {
        characterCount = map[char];
      }
    }
  }
  const mapSize = Object.keys(map).length;
  if (mapSize === MAX && characterCount === 1) {
    return wildcards % MAX === 0;
  }
  if (mapSize < MAX && characterCount === 1 && wildcards <= (MAX - mapSize)) {
    return true;
  }
  if (wildcards === s.length) {
    return true;
  }

  for (const char in map) {
    while (map[char] + 1 <= characterCount) {
      map[char]++;
      wildcards--;
    }
    if (wildcards < 0) return false;
  }
  if (wildcards % characterCount === 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I am testing the code against the below inputs

```
1: "a" should return true
2: "ab" should return true
3: "abc" should return true
4: "abcb" should return false
5: "Aaa" should return false
6: "abcb*" should return false
7: "abcb**" shoud return true
8: "***********" should return true
9: "" should return true
10: "abd*xdx*yba*" should return true
11: "aabb***" should return false
12: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" should return false
13: "JB**JTIT*****EY" should return false
```

Comment: You've made it more difficult that it is, all you need is to make sure all numbersare the same `Object.values(map).every((e, i, a) => e == a[0])`

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: nevermind, that was without wildcards.

Comment: Well, you didn't even say what tests don't pass

Comment: I want the program to be able to detect various valid wildcard arrangements. example.
`console.log(balanced("aabb***"))` should return false.
`console.log(balanced("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ*"))` should return false
`console.log(balanced("Z*J*E*MZI*IMKYN***C**P*W*I*QI*JVQUB***J**FMHDG**CCH"))` should return false

Answer (score 0):

```
12: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" should return false
```

no, it should return `true`
All other tests pass

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitest-dev-vitest-afgmgj?file=balanced.test.ts&initialPath=__vitest__

Comment: Yeah my bad. I found a solution already. Thank you by the way

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar problem. I just twisted the solution a little bit.

```
const factorPairs = (n: number) =>
  [...Array(Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n)))].map((_, i) => i + 1)
    .flatMap(f => n % f == 0 ? [[f, n / f], [n / f, f]] : []);

const balanced = (s: string): boolean => {
  if (!s) return true;
  const ss = s.split('');
  const chars = [...new Set(ss.filter(s => s !== '*'))];
  const counts = ss.reduce(
    (counts, s) => s === '*' ? counts : ((counts[s] += 1), counts),
    Object.fromEntries(chars.map(l => [l, 0]))
  );
  const maxCount = Math.max(...Object.values(counts));
  return factorPairs(ss.length).some(
    ([count, letters]) =>
      letters <= 52 &&
      letters >= chars.length &&
      count >= maxCount
  );
};
```

[link to original solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67977081/working-with-equal-occurrences-of-characters-in-a-string-of-characters)